# If $\sum c_n$ is convergent where $c_n = a_1b_n + \cdots +a_nb_1$, then $\sum c_n = \sum a_n\sum b_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ is convergent and $c_n = a_1b_n + \cdots + a_nb_1$. Prove that if $\sum c_n$ is convergent then $\sum c_n = \sum a_n \sum b_n$.

This question has been answered using **Abel's Lemma** in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2771606/if-sum-a-n-and-sum-b-n-and-their-convolution-sum-c-n-converge-then-s) post. But I am looking forward to a more basic solution which only uses basic definition and Cauchy's convergence test.

Comment: X,T,Chen. Absolute convergence of$ \sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n $?

Comment: @PeterSzilas nope. Just conditionally converge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by **Cesaro Theorem** of Cauchy product.[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2301870)