Cauchy Product of Summable Sequences is Cesàro Summable
According to Wikipedia, if $a_\bullet,b_\bullet$ are real (or complex) sequences such that $\sum_n a_n\to A$ and $\sum_n b_n\to B$, then
$$\boxed{\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=0}^i a_{k}b_{i-k}=AB}$$
Do you know where I can find a proof of this result? If not, I would also be satisfied with a self-contained proof of the following immediate corollary which I haven't been able to prove

Corollary: If $\sum_na_n\to A,\sum_nb_n\to B, \sum_na'_n\to A', \sum_nb'_n\to B'$, then it follows that
$$\boxed{\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}\right)_{n\geq0}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^na'_kb'_{n-k}\right)_{n\geq0}\Rightarrow AB=A'B'}$$

Thanks in advance! (This is not homework, btw. I was just on that Wikipedia page and that statement piqued my curiosity.)

This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2301870/42969

@MartinR Oh yes! Thanks a lot! That totally answers my question.

Oops, it seems like I answered an almost identical answer as in Martin R's link. :s

Here we prove:

Lemma. Let $A_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k$ and $B_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} b_k$. Then
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{k} a_j b_{k-j} = \sum_{n=0}^{N} A_n B_{N-n}. $$

Proof of Lemma. We prove the claim by induction on $N$.

(Base case) When $N = 0$, both sides are $a_0 b_0$, hence the equality holds.

(Induction step) Assume the claim holds for $N \geq 0$. Then the increment of the left-hand side when $N$ is increased by $1$ to $N+1$ is
\begin{align*}
&\biggl[ \sum_{n=0}^{N+1} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{k} a_j b_{k-j} \biggr] - \biggl[ \sum_{n=0}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{k} a_j b_{k-j} \biggr] 
= \sum_{k=0}^{N+1} \sum_{j=0}^{k} a_j b_{k-j}.
\end{align*}
On the other hand, the increment of the right-hand side is
\begin{align*}
\biggl[ \sum_{n=0}^{N+1} A_n B_{N+1-n} \biggr] - \biggl[ \sum_{n=0}^{N} A_n B_{N-n} \biggr]
&= \sum_{n=0}^{N+1} A_n b_{N+1 - n}.
\end{align*}
It is not hard to check that both sides are the sum of $a_p b_q$'s for which $p, q \geq 0$ and $p + q \leq N$, establishing the induction step.


Therefore the lemma follows from the principle of mathematical induction. $\square$
Using this lemma, we can prove:

Theorem. Suppose

$(a_n)$ is ordinary summable, and
$(b_n)$ has bounded partial sums and is Cesàro summable.

Then the Cauchy product $((a\bullet b)_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k b_{n-k})$ is also Cesàro summable, and
$$ \biggl[ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \biggr]\biggl[ \text{C-} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n \biggr]
= \text{C-} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a \bullet b)_n $$

Proof. Let $A_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k$ and $B_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} b_k$. Also, write $A = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ and $B = \text{C-} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$ for simplicity. Then by the above lemma,
\begin{align*}
&\left| \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^{k} a_j b_{k-j} - AB \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^{N} A_n B_{N-n} - AB \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^{N} (A_n - A) B_{N-n} + \frac{1}{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^{N} A B_{N-n} - A B \right| \\
&\leq (\sup_n |B_n|) \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N} |A_n - A|}{N+1} + |A| \left| \frac{\sum_{n=0}^{N} B_{N-n}}{N+1} - B \right|.
\end{align*}
Now as $N \to \infty$, the first term vanishes by Stolz–Cesàro theorem. On the other hand, the second term vanishes because  $(b_n)$ is Cesàro summable. Therefore the desired claim follows. $\square$
